# How to normalize Api response using Ramda

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, ramda.js

How can i normalize this api response using ramda:

```
appointmentsConfig: Object
   isEnable: true
   isReadonly: false
   reminderInAdvanceMinutes: 1440
   __proto__: Object
tasksConfigs: Array(4)
   0: Object
      isEnable: true
      isReadonly: false
      reminderInAdvanceMinutes: 15
      reminderRepeatIntervalMinutes: 10
      remindersNumber: 0
      shouldRepeatUntilTaskDone: true
      taskTypeGroupAlias: "Medications"
      taskTypes: Array(1)
      __proto__: Object
   1: Object
      isEnable: true
      isReadonly: false
      reminderInAdvanceMinutes: 15
      reminderRepeatIntervalMinutes: 10
      remindersNumber: 0
      shouldRepeatUntilTaskDone: true
      taskTypeGroupAlias: "Measurements"
      taskTypes: Array(2)
      __proto__: Object
...etc.
```

to this object:

```
    {
  "Medications": {
    "taskTypeGroupAlias": "Medications",
    "taskTypes": [
      "MedicationTask"
    ],
    "isReadonly": false,
    "isEnable": true,
    "shouldRepeatUntilTaskDone": true,
    "remindersNumber": 0,
    "reminderRepeatIntervalMinutes": 10,
    "reminderInAdvanceMinutes": 15
  },
```

> ...and the same Measurements, Surveys, Tasks objects
>
> ...and one different object below

```
  "Visits": {
    "isReadonly": false,
    "isEnable": true,
    "reminderInAdvanceMinutes": 1440
  }
}
```

Visits - it is an object appointmentsConfig.

I guess i have to use reduceBy method, but i can not resolve this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `tasksConfigs` has a single item for each `taskTypeGroupAlias`  type, you can use R.indexBy:

```
R.indexBy(R.prop('taskTypeGroupAlias'), response.tasksConfigs);
```

However, if each `taskTypeGroupAlias` might appear multiple times, you should consider R.groupBy:

```
R.groupBy(R.prop('taskTypeGroupAlias'), response.tasksConfigs);
```

This will return an object of arrays, where each array contains objects with the same `taskTypeGroupAlias`:

```
{
  Medications: [],
  Measurements: [],
  Surveys: [],
  Tasks: [],
  Visits: [],
}
```

Comment: I have only one item for each `taskTypeGroupAlias` type. Could you help me with Visits? My bad that i wasn't define whole situation well. I need also normalize `appointmentsConfig: Object
   isEnable: true
   isReadonly: false
   reminderInAdvanceMinutes: 1440
   __proto__: Object`.   to Visits. How can i do this?

Comment: Instead of pasting from the console. Create an example of actual input data (not huge), and expected result.

Comment: how can i turn {
  Medications: [],
  Measurements: [],
  Surveys: [],
  Tasks: [],
  Visits: [],
} to tasksConfigs: Array(4)
   0: Object
      isEnable: true
      isReadonly: false
      reminderInAdvanceMinutes: 15
      reminderRepeatIntervalMinutes: 10
      remindersNumber: 0
      shouldRepeatUntilTaskDone: true
      taskTypeGroupAlias: "Medications"
      taskTypes: Array(1)
      __proto__: Object
   ...etc

Comment: i need to return the old object for the post request (body)